# check if an array field is empty and print a warning message

Tags: php

I have a form in a php script, that has 2 fields ("year" and "web"). After pressing submit, the values of the form stored in an array named "save_job". All I want is to make my script to print a warning message if the user has left empty the field "web".
Here is my code:

```
<?php  

if(empty($_POST) === false){

 if(  empty($errors) === true  ){

        //displays error message if year is not a number

        if( preg_match("&[^0-9s ]&",$_POST['year']) ){
            $errors[]='<font color="#963">Year must contain 0-9 characters and spaces</font>';
        } preg_replace("&[^0-9s ]&","",$_POST['year']); 


        }
 }

?>


    <form   action=""   method="POST"  >   


    <?php 
        if ( isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success'])===true ){
            echo'</br><h3>Section "My News" Updated Sucessfuly!</h3>';?>
            <?php 
        }else{
                if( empty($_POST) === false  &&  empty($errors) === true ){
                    $save_job = array(
                                        'year' => $_POST['year'],
                                        'web' => $_POST['web'],
                                        'user_id' => $session_user_id,
                                        );

                            //checks if "web" field in $save_job array is empty     

                            if(!empty($save_job['web']) === true ){
                                echo $save_job['web'] ;
                            } else{
                                echo"web field is empty";
                            }




                }else if ( empty($errors) === false ){
                    echo output_errors($errors);
                    echo'</br></br>';
                }

                ?>

    Year<input name="year" type="text" size="2" />

    Web Site<input name="web" type="text" size="50" />

<input type="submit" value="" name="submit"   />

</form> 

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: You never set `$error` when `$save_job['web']` is empty.

Comment: any idea how to set $error when $save_job['web'] is empty?

Comment: Do it in the `else` clause where you echo "web field is empty"`

Comment: is it possible to show me how you will write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                        if(!empty($save_job['web']) === true ){
                            echo $save_job['web'] ;
                        } else{
                            echo"web field is empty";
                            $errors[] = <font color="#963">Web field is empty</font>';
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the [`isset()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and a simple conditional expression:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['web'] ) && $_POST['web'] != '' ){
  // here you know know for certain that 
  // there is a non empty value in $_POST['web'].
}
```

Comment: The string `0` will return false if you run `empty()` on it. I'm not sure that this is the desired behavior...